# Why doesn't Walden kick Alan out?

Tags: two-and-a-half-men

In Two and Half Men, Charlie kept Alan around since they were brothers from the same mother. But why does Walden continue to keep him around? He's certainly not paying rent, helping and certainly not *in love*! I can understand why he would wanna keep Jenny and her girlfriend around (I mean, who wouldn't?), but why Alan?

Comment: My question is strictly regarding Walden, not Charlie, since he was his brother so it made sense. This thing with Walden....doesn't make the slightest sense !

Comment: The other question dabbles into both; Alan vs. Charlie and Alan vs. Walden.

Comment: Yes, exactly. So what's the deal with Walden ? Please don't tell me it's another Sherlock-Watson kinda thing, where one needs the other one more. Walden doesn't need Alan, right ?

Comment: Check the second part of my answer to the other question. Overall, Alan is just a master in playing the needy. Given Walden's experiences/background he somehow just can't kick him out without feeling really guilty.

Comment: Yeah, but doesn't he fake that heart attack ?